# load event not triggered in zeroclipboard.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, zeroclipboard

I'm using zeroclipboard.js in my application to copy the text from the div. its working fine when we run it in visual studio but its nor working in file open mode `file:///`. zeroclipboard.swf file is correctly loaded in the file open mode. After a long search i noticed that `load` event is not triggered in the file open mode but load event is triggered on visual studio. how can i overcome this issue and how to trigger the load event in file open mode.

Here is some code which i used,

```
clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
clip.setHandCursor(true);
clip.glue('copy_button');
var $copyButton = $('#copy_button');

clip.addEventListener('load', function () {
    alert('load');
});

clip.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
    alert('mouse down');  
});

clip.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    alert('mouse up');  
});
```

The above code is working in vs but not in file open mode. please help me.